# Linking page in Flexdashboard without it being in Navbar

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I'm trying to have one dashboard page link to another but I don't want the linked page to be in the navbar. For some reason I can't find a way to do this. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

This can be accomplished by adding the {.hidden} attribute to the page you want to hide from the navigation bar. For example:

```
---
title: "Hiding Pages"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

Link to [Page 3](#page-3)


Page 2 
=====================================  


Page 3 {.hidden}
=====================================
```